# Ask Google to Stop Googlebot Crawl

Tags: bandwidth, googlebot

Okay, so a Wordpress gallery plugin lead to a massive headache - with about 17 galleries having their own pagination, the links within created what might as well be infinite number of variant URLs combining the various query variables from each gallery.

As such, Google has been not so smart and has been **HAMMERING** the server to the tune of 4 gigs an hour prior to my actions, and about 800 requests a minute on the same page sending the server load up to 30 at one point.

It's been about 12 hours, and regardless of the changes I've made, Google is not listening (yet) and is still hammering away.

My question is: Is there a way to contact Google support and tell them to shut their misbehaving bot down on a particular website?

I want a more immediate solution as I do not enjoy the server being bombarded.

---

Before you say it, even though this isn't what I'm asking about, I've done the following:

1. Redirected all traffic using the misused query variable back to the Googlebot IP in hopes that the bot being forwarded back to itself will be a wake up call that something is not right with the URL. (I don't care if this is a bad idea)
2. Blocking the most active IP address from accessing that site.
3. Disabled the URLs from being created by the troubled plugin.
4. In Google Webmaster Tools/Search Console, I've set the URL parameters to "No: Doesn't affect page content" for the query variables.

Regardless of all of this, Google is still hammering away at 800 requests per minute/13 requests a second.

Yes, I could just wait it out, but I'm looking for a "HEY GOOGLE! STOP WHAT YOU ARE DOING!" solution besides being patient and allowing resources to be wasted.

Comment: Also, I do not want to block Google in the robots.txt file or set a limit in GWT/SC because they will have effects in how Google crawls the site after it rights itself.

Comment: Sounds like you need a [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/). If you don't want to block Google Bot outright, maybe you should set a `Crawl-delay`.

Comment: As mentioned, I do not want to affect future crawling. I imagine that Google will stop its DOS attack in a matter of hours, but I want a solution to tell them right now to stop it, that they caused the site to go offline by their DOS attack type of activity.